# how to calculate different variable list on python

Tags: python, list, math

Using the same data, make a Python coding for ∑XiYi

Data

X = 4   6   8   10  14  16  20  22  24  28

Y = 30  18  22  28  14  22  16  8   20  8

For example:

Test Result

print(XiYi)

[120, 108, 176, 280, 196, 352, 320, 176, 480, 224]

print(sumXiYi)

2432

Answer (score 1):

You can use zip:

```py
X = [4, 6, 8, 10, 14, 16, 20, 22, 24, 28]
Y = [30, 18, 22, 28, 14, 22, 16, 8, 20, 8]
print(sum(x*y for x,y in zip(X,Y)))
```

Output:

```
2432
```

Comment: You have redundant brackets, `print(sum(x*y for x,y in zip(X,Y)))` is fine

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
X = [4, 6, 8, 10, 14, 16, 20, 22, 24, 28]
Y = [30, 18, 22, 28, 14, 22, 16, 8, 20, 8]
XiYi = [Y[i]*x for i, x in enumerate(X)]

print(XiYi)
[120, 108, 176, 280, 196, 352, 320, 176, 480, 224]

print(sum(XiYi))
2432
```